# Excel - keyboard shortcut to "Enable Content" instead of mouse?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to "Enable Content" instead of using a mouse?

[image: Enable Content]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me know if the below shortcut is working for you:

"Alt + F + I + N".  Then press Enter

P.S. - I know this is not so short, but works for me.

Comment: +1. This works.

Answer (score 1):

Alt + F + I + E

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

From [this Microsoft site](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/keyboard-shortcut-to-unprotect-the-file/e082dda3-5445-4c5c-b294-11c5ff288871?db=5):

> This works in Word/Excel/Powerpoint:
>
> Click on File > Options
>
> Click on 'Quick Access Toolbar'
>
> Choose commands from:
>
> Select - 'All Commands'
>
> Scroll down to 'Enable Editing'
>
> Select it and Click on 'Add'
>
> An icon will appear at the very top left of Excel/Word/Powerpoint.
>
> Open a document that has the message 'Protected View This file
>   originated from an Internet location and might be unsafe.....'
>
> Press Alt button a maximum of 4 times. This enables you to access the
>   main menu items by typing a letter - but also allows you to access the
>   'Quick Access Toolbar' using numbers.
>
> The 'Enable Editing' icon looks like a notepad with a pencil, it
>   should have a 2 next to it.
>
> Therefore the full command is Alt x 4 then press '2' for the pop up
>   to go away.

The specific number will vary, depending on how many other items are already present in the Quick Access Toolbar.

I only needed to hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> once.

Comment: Hmm, that's not working for me. The "Enable Editing" icon is greyed out, I assume because I can already edit the document, and I need to "Enable Content," because macros are disabled by default...

Comment: Ahhh. I see what you mean. I found a solution for "Enable Editing", but not for "Enable Content". I'll keep looking.

Answer (score -1):

Use the same shortcut you used to save a file. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: This will not work.

Answer (score -1):

For me, I hit F2 (or whatever button you use to begin editing the contents of a cell). The file should come up with a popup that says something about you having to enable editing to edit cells, from which point you just hit enter on "Enable Editing".

Full shortcut:

1. Press <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Arrow one option to the left ("Enable Editing")
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: This will not work.

Comment: This works fine for "Enable Editing" but not "Enable Content"

Answer (score -1):

Not a shortcut but click F2 anywhere in the sheet and then move arrow to left, click enter.

Comment: This will not work.